# How to prevent FireTV from sleeping via a website (not an app) like youtube.com/tv?

Tags: amazon-fire-tv

I know that you can prevent sleep mode from an Amazon app (packaged or hybrid webapp) but I'm wondering how to do it from a website running in the firefox browser, eg. the youtube.com/tv site will play video on FireTV for extended periods without sleeping.